# Data labels with "callout" shape misses pointing triangle for short text

Tags: highcharts

For short labels (1-2 symbols) callout shape is shown without pointer which may be confusing with complex charts. Can this be fixed somehow?
[image]

**Update1:**

Editor: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-s6upn2

Result: https://js-s6upn2.stackblitz.io

**Update2 (fixed workaround):**

top and bottom verticalAlign handled, editor updated

```
Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.callout = function(x, y, w, h, options) {
    const arrowLength = 6;
    const halfDistance = 6;
    const r = Math.min((options && options.r) || 0, w, h);
    // const safeDistance = r + halfDistance;
    const anchorX = options && options.anchorX;
    const anchorY = options && options.anchorY;

    const path = [
        'M', x + r, y,
        'L', x + w - r, y, // top side
        'C', x + w, y, x + w, y, x + w, y + r, // top-right corner
        'L', x + w, y + h - r, // right side
        'C', x + w, y + h, x + w, y + h, x + w - r, y + h, // bottom-right corner
        'L', x + r, y + h, // bottom side
        'C', x, y + h, x, y + h, x, y + h - r, // bottom-left corner
        'L', x, y + r, // left side
        'C', x, y, x, y, x + r, y // top-left corner
    ];

    path.splice(
        anchorY >= 0 ? 23 : 3,
        3,
        'L', anchorX + halfDistance > x + w ? x + w : anchorX + halfDistance, anchorY >= 0 ? y + h : y,
        anchorX, anchorY >= 0 ? y + h + arrowLength : y - arrowLength,
        anchorX - halfDistance >= x ? anchorX - halfDistance : x, anchorY >= 0 ? y + h : y,
        x + r, anchorY >= 0 ? y + h : y
    );

    return path;
};
```

**Update3**

Actually looks like this realization should handle many more corner cases, for example it breaks "split" type tooltips

[image]

So I suggest to call this shape "callout2" and use for top/bottom data labels only.

Comment: Hi Dimanoid, Could you provide me with some minimal live example? `dataLabels` with `callout` shape seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pja39btm/

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-s6upn2
Sorry for the size, config has quite a complex logic while generated, so I just exported the whole Chart.options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem looks like bug, so I reported it on Highcharts github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10020

To workaround, you can overwrite the `callout` shape:

```
Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.callout = function(x, y, w, h, options) {
    var arrowLength = 6,
        halfDistance = 6,
        r = Math.min((options && options.r) || 0, w, h),
        safeDistance = r + halfDistance,
        anchorX = options && options.anchorX,
        anchorY = options && options.anchorY,
        path;

    path = [
        'M', x + r, y,
        'L', x + w - r, y, // top side
        'C', x + w, y, x + w, y, x + w, y + r, // top-right corner
        'L', x + w, y + h - r, // right side
        'C', x + w, y + h, x + w, y + h, x + w - r, y + h, // bottom-rgt
        'L', x + r, y + h, // bottom side
        'C', x, y + h, x, y + h, x, y + h - r, // bottom-left corner
        'L', x, y + r, // left side
        'C', x, y, x, y, x + r, y // top-left corner
    ];

    path.splice(
        23,
        3,
        'L', anchorX + halfDistance, y + h,
        anchorX, y + h + arrowLength,
        anchorX - halfDistance, y + h,
        x + r, y + h
    );

    return path;
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o0j76Lbt/

Comment: Thank you, I ended up with my own shape implementation too, just thought I missed some parameters.

Comment: I added a few fixes to handle case when label is bottom aligned and when the dot is at the left or right edge and no additional padding there too